# Places to seat/sleep at SFO pre-security

Tags: airports, sleeping, sfo

I wonder if there any seat or couch at the pre security area in SFO.

Best,

Answer (score 3):

From [the usual reference for this sort of thing](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/sanfrancisco.htm):

> The quietest spot may be at Terminal 3 (landside). You can move furniture around pretty easily to create some privacy. Arrive early and there may be bigger bench-style couches.

There's definitely some benches in various departure areas before security as well.  They generally don't look very comfortable to me, but they're there.

Comment: Yeah, I know that webpage but most the things listed there are for post security check. Thanks though!